# Why am I receiving empty strings after receiving valid data from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Firebase, I'm trying to display to the user people they have matched with. I already have valid data for testing this and I have already run tests with sample data to see if everything else works.

Now, when I use real data from Firebase, problems occur.

This is what I have for code:

```
public String username = "";
public String profileImage = "";
public String discussion = "";
private void FetchMatchInformation(final String key, final String choice) {
    DatabaseReference matchDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("answers").child(key);

    matchDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String opposite = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                if(opposite.equals("agree") && choice.equals("disagree")) {
                    DatabaseReference found = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(postSnapshot.getKey());
                    found.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                if(postSnapshot.getKey().equals("username")) {
                                    username = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                }
                                if(postSnapshot.getKey().equals("providerId")) {
                                    String provider = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                    if(provider.equals("google.com")) {
                                        Uri photoUrl = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl();
                                        String originalPieceOfUrl = "s96-c/photo.jpg";
                                        String newPieceOfUrlToAdd = "s400-c/photo.jpg";
                                        String photoPath = photoUrl.toString();
                                        String newString = photoPath.replace(originalPieceOfUrl, newPieceOfUrlToAdd);
                                        profileImage = newString;
                                    } else if(provider.equals("facebook.com")) {
                                        profileImage = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString() + "?type=large";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("debates").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                if(postSnapshot.getKey().equals(key)) {
                                    discussion = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                    break;
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    MessagesObject objDisc = new MessagesObject(username, discussion, profileImage);
                    resultsMessages.add(objDisc);
                    mMessagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if(opposite.equals("disagree") && choice.equals("agree")) {
                    DatabaseReference found = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(postSnapshot.getKey());
                    found.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                if(postSnapshot.getKey().equals("username")) {
                                    username = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                }
                                if(postSnapshot.getKey().equals("providerId")) {
                                    String provider = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                    if(provider.equals("google.com")) {
                                        Uri photoUrl = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl();
                                        String originalPieceOfUrl = "s96-c/photo.jpg";
                                        String newPieceOfUrlToAdd = "s400-c/photo.jpg";
                                        String photoPath = photoUrl.toString();
                                        String newString = photoPath.replace(originalPieceOfUrl, newPieceOfUrlToAdd);
                                        profileImage = newString;
                                    } else if(provider.equals("facebook.com")) {
                                        profileImage = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString() + "?type=large";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("debates").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                if(postSnapshot.getKey().equals(key)) {
                                    discussion = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                    break;
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    MessagesObject objDisc = new MessagesObject(username, discussion, profileImage);
                    resultsMessages.add(objDisc);
                    mMessagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

So what's happening is I'm getting the user's username, their profile image, and figuring out the value, which I called `discussion` after determining the valid key. These values are all being accessed from different tree structures from the same real-time database.

Now, at the end of the `if` or `else-if` statement, I create and instantiate the `MessagesObject` by passing in the username, profile image, and discussion variables. I then add this object to the `List<MessagesObject>` called `resultMessages`. I then notify my custom adapter `mMessagesAdapter` that the data has changed.

Like I said, all the other pieces of code work perfectly fine. It's just when I pass `username`, `discussion`, and `profileImage` it always passes an empty string. I know this from using the debugger.

Why is that? It should not be doing that.